# Need help removing a legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I need to fix the following code

```
Plot[V[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-3, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 22, Bold], 
   Style["V(x)", FontSize -> 22, Bold]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

to remove the "---V(x)" right next to the Plot. It makes no sense because it's the only function being plotted.

[image: result of the code.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the option  `PlotLegends -> None`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks! that's what I was looking for. Did the Legend emerge from the "Detailed" PlotTheme?

Comment: Yes, `PlotTheme  -> "Detailed"` adds the option `PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach to remove the legend: Take the first `Part` of `Plot` output:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x] - 1, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-3, 1}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 22, Bold], Style["V(x)", FontSize -> 22, Bold]},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
First @ plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @kglr stated, this will do:

```
Plot[V[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-3, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 22, Bold], 
   Style["V(x)", FontSize -> 22, Bold]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> None]
```

and the Plot is fixed.